# How can do Color Separation or remove Pantone(Spot Colors) and CMYK colors in PDF file?

Tags: pdf, pdf.js, cmyk, pdf-manipulation, pantone

We are developing the application where we're using PDF.Js library to render the PDF in Browser. I am open to approaches of any language and libraries.

- We are developing color separation feature in my application similar to this application by PDFTron in the below mentioned link.
  [Apryse](https://showcase.apryse.com/color-separation/)
- We have a PDF which consists of multiple Pantone and CMYK colors in it. List of colors present in the PDF are mentioned in the left side bar under Color Separation tab as shown in the below picture.
  [Original PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMVj2.png)
- Now by unchecking any of the color we should be able to remove the selected color in the provided PDF and show the resultant PDF as shown in the below picture.
  [Resultant PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZdJu.png)